# How to differentiate orders of two different stores of same seller on amazon, using MWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral, mws

I am listing orders from amazon store on my application.
One seller on my app have 2 stores 1 for North America & 1 for Canada.

As I am getting these orders using MWS Order APi with different service urls for both the stores, for every store its fetching all the orders from both the stores resulting duplicate records.

Does anyone know how to overcome this situation.

Service URL for Canada = 'https://mws.amazonservices.ca'
Service URL for North America = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com'
I have same MWS Auth token for both the stores as they belong to same seller.

Thanks in advance.